# Solving a system of ODEs given in matrix notation

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

Is it possible to solve above ODE in Mathematica for φ and ψ, where 
$∇^2=∂^2/(∂r^2) + 1/r\ ∂/∂r$?

```
Eq1 = {α*M*D[ψ[r, t], {r, 2}] + α*M*
      D[ψ[r, t], r] + (λ + 2)*
      D[ϕ[r, t], {r, 2}] + ((λ + 1)*D[ϕ[r, t], r])/
      r == p*s*ψ[r, t] + s^2*ϕ[r, t]};
Eq2 = {α*M*D[ϕ[r, t], {r, 2}] + 
     M*D[ψ[r, t], {r, 2}] + α*M*D[ϕ[r, t], r] + 
     M*D[ψ[r, t], r] == 
    b*s*ψ[r, t] + m*s^2*ψ[r, t] + p*s^2*ϕ[r, t]};

DSolve[{Eq1, Eq2}, {ϕ[r, t], ψ[r, t]}, r]
```

What is wrong here? Can I solve this way using `Dsolve`?

Comment: Do you think these PDEs have an analytic solution?

Comment: @KraZug It does. The solutions is in terms of Bessels functions.This problem is from a paper " Transient Response of a circular cavity in a Poroelastic Medium" (1993).

Comment: Can you check your Mathematica versions of the equations, I don't think they are correct. There is no $1/r$ in `Eq2`, and there is a $(\lambda+1)$ term.